# Function with two variadic parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I intend to implement a template function which would accept two functions and their parameters list and then created two wrappers. I have already implemented similar solution to accept two function and create wrapper using `std::bind()` but using hard-coded parameters. The solution is something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
myWrapper (T2 func1, T4 func2) {
  std::function<T1>ff = std::bind(func1, 1, placeholders::_1);
  std::function<T3>ff = std::bind(func1, 110, 20, "something");
}
```

As you see the parameters to `std::bind()` are hard-coded in both cases which I would like to read them through `myWrapper()` function. Is there any way to read two variadic templates (list of variables of arbitrary length and type) and send them to two `std::bind()` calls I have in the above code?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you'd like the function to be called?

Comment: Well, actually I don't know! That is the question! :) I generally want something like this:

template <typename... Args>
void fun2(variadicStruct<Args...> args) {
  auto wrappedFunc1 = std::bind(originalFunc1, args.args1);
  auto wrappedFunc2 = std::bind(originalFunc2, args.args2);
}

fun2({(this, std::placeholders::_1), (this, 1, 2)});

where "this, std::placeholders::_1" will be passed to the wrapper of the first function and "this, 1, 2" will be passed to the wrapper of the second function. This is my intention.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean with "I can read one variadic input parameter without any problem"?

Comment: Yes sure! You always can have something like this:

template <typename... Args>
void fun2(int arg1, int arg2, Args ..args) {
  // Do something with arguments.
}

because the compiler can successfully deduce two first parameters and then deduce the rest as variadic. But having two variadics will make the parameters list non-deduceable. That is the problem!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your code example with `variadicStruct`. You define it with a single template parameter, `T`, but in `fun2()` you use it as receiving a variadic list of template types (`Args...`). Do you mean something type `template <typename ... Args> struct variadicStruct { std::tuple<Args...> args1; std::tuple<Args...> args2; };` ?

Comment: Do you have two lists of identical types (same types, same lengths) or two different lists (different types and different lengths)?

Comment: max66: I think the code snippet would work anyway because I use T template in struct which can be defined as variadic later. But anyway, answering your question, yes I need two lists of parameters which I never know their length and the type of data in them. The data types in each list is not same neither as it will be parameters list to a function.

Comment: Sorry but... your question is too vague if you present an example like this that "can be define as variadic later". I need to understand now how is defined `variadicStruct`, how do you to want to call `fun2()` and what do you want to do with this two list of parameters. Now I have only a great confusion in my mind and I suspect I'm not alone. I suggest you to rewrite completely this question (or, better, delete and write another) giving an understandable description of your problem

Comment: Changed the question! Hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you want but I suppose you need to use `std::tuple` (or something similar) to separate the two sequences of args.

The following is an full working example of what I mean, according what I've understand of what do you want.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2,
          std::size_t ... Is1, std::size_t ... Is2>
auto myWrapperH (T3 func1, T4 func2, std::tuple<Ts1...> const & tp1,
                 std::tuple<Ts2...> const & tp2,
                 std::index_sequence<Is1...> const &,
                 std::index_sequence<Is2...> const &)
 {
   T1 f1 = std::bind(func1, std::get<Is1>(tp1)...);
   T2 f2 = std::bind(func2, std::get<Is2>(tp2)...);

   return std::make_pair(f1, f2);
 }

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
auto myWrapper (T3 func1, T4 func2, std::tuple<Ts1...> const & tp1,
                std::tuple<Ts2...> const & tp2)
 { return myWrapperH<T1, T2>(func1, func2, tp1, tp2,
                             std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts1)>{},
                             std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts2)>{}); }

int foo (int a, int b)
 { return a+b; }

std::size_t bar (int a, int b, std::string const & str)
 { return str.size() + a + b; }

int main ()
 {
   using fType1 = std::function<int(int)>;
   using fType2 = std::function<long()>;

   auto mwr = myWrapper<fType1, fType2>(&foo, &bar,
                 std::make_tuple(1, std::placeholders::_1),
                 std::make_tuple(110, 20, std::string{"something"}));

   std::cout << mwr.first(5) << std::endl; // print   6
   std::cout << mwr.second() << std::endl; // print 139
 }
```

Unfortunately is a C++14 code (`auto` return type; `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`) but should be easy to adapt in C++11.

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Banan (thanks!) there is no need to explicit the type of returned functions (`T1`, `T2`).

Using the `auto` return type the example can be simplified as follows

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename F1, typename F2, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2,
          std::size_t ... Is1, std::size_t ... Is2>
auto myWrapperH (F1 func1, F2 func2, std::tuple<Ts1...> const & tp1,
                 std::tuple<Ts2...> const & tp2,
                 std::index_sequence<Is1...> const &,
                 std::index_sequence<Is2...> const &)
 { return std::make_pair(std::bind(func1, std::get<Is1>(tp1)...),
                         std::bind(func2, std::get<Is2>(tp2)...)); }

template <typename F1, typename F2, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
auto myWrapper (F1 func1, F2 func2, std::tuple<Ts1...> const & tp1,
                std::tuple<Ts2...> const & tp2)
 { return myWrapperH(func1, func2, tp1, tp2,
                     std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts1)>{},
                     std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts2)>{}); }

int foo (int a, int b)
 { return a+b; }

std::size_t bar (int a, int b, std::string const & str)
 { return str.size() + a + b; }

int main ()
 {
   auto mwr = myWrapper(&foo, &bar,
                 std::make_tuple(1, std::placeholders::_1),
                 std::make_tuple(110, 20, std::string{"something"}));

   std::cout << mwr.first(5) << std::endl; // print   6
   std::cout << mwr.second() << std::endl; // print 139
 }
```

Comment: Nice solution, I was working on something similar myself. Can you remove the need for explicitly supplying `myWrapper` with `fType1` and `fType2`? Seems like something that could be deduced by the compiler :)

Comment: @Banan - thanks; there is no need using the `auto` return value; but I don't know if it's a good idea because I don't know why the OP require to explicit it. But maybe I explicit this...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your idea of a `variadicStruct` you may wish to have a look at [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

```
template<class... Ts, class... Us>
void do_stuff(const std::tuple<Ts...>&, const std::tuple<Us...>&) {
  std::cout << "two variadic packs with " << sizeof...(Ts)
        << " and " << sizeof...(Us) << " elements." << std::endl;
}
```

To be called like this:

```
do_stuff(std::make_tuple(4.7, 'x', 1.0, 4, 8l), std::make_tuple("foo", 1));
```

Comment: It would be very good to use tuples as well. But the problem was unpacking data from tuples. Now I see that you have easily unpacked them by reading Ts and Us directly. I will try it. I hope it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dan `std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>` is a huge help in unpacking tuples. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: Thanks! I hope this is not part of C++14/17 because we are quite limited to C++11 so far.

Comment: @Dan: `std::tuple` has been introduced with C++11 and should work right away. However, `std::index_sequence` and helpers (as suggested by @aschepler) are C++14. The latter could be replaced by some equivalent helper from another library/namespace. Note that good implementations of `std::make_index_sequence` etc. should aim for logarithmic recursion depth and moreover optimize the benefit of memoization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) and [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), for example:

```
template <typename R, typename Func1, typename Args1>
void wrapper (Func1 f1, Args1 a1)
{
    std::function<R> wrapped1 = [f1, a1]{ return std::apply(f1, a1); };
}

// ...

auto deg_to_rad = [](int x){ return x / 180.f * 3.1415f; };
wrapper<float>(deg_to_rad, std::make_tuple(45));
```

`std::apply` requires C++17 support. However, the [linked page on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) contains a possible implementation that works in C++11.